# How to link each employee to his manager and select the minimum DOB?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select the oldest DOB of the employee under the manager who doesn't have a manager.
**Edit**
I want group all employees under a top Manager (null on manager) and get the first DOB on that group

Data looks like.

```
employe_ID  DOB           manager
10001       1-Jan-1988    (NULL)
10010       5-Feb-1989    10001
10100       8-Mar-1990    10010
90001       1-Jan-1987    (NULL)
90010       5-Feb-1986    90001
90100       8-Mar-1987    90010
```

I want data like

```
employe_ID  DOB           
10001       1-Jan-1988
10010       1-Jan-1988
10100       1-Jan-1988
90001       5-Feb-1986
90010       5-Feb-1986
90100       5-Feb-1986
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `connect by prior, connect_by_root` and `MIN(DOB) over partition by`

```
select employee_id, MIN(DOB) over (partition by topManager) MINDOBperManager, topManager
  from (
select t.*, connect_by_root employee_id topManager
 from t
 start with manager is null
 connect by prior employee_id = manager) t1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
EMPL  MINDOBPERMANAGER    TOPMANAGER
----- ------------------- ----------
10001 01-01-1988 00:00:00      10001
10010 01-01-1988 00:00:00      10001
10100 01-01-1988 00:00:00      10001
90001 05-02-1986 00:00:00      90001
90010 05-02-1986 00:00:00      90001
90100 05-02-1986 00:00:00      90001
```